# How to put multiple items in Tabs and make them scrollable

Tags: react-native, native-base

[image]

I have 5 tabs like the example above.

My Tabs have too many letters and they exceeded the window's width (one of element make another line). The width of tab is always window's width divided by 5 (window's width/5). 
So I want to make **my tabs' elements scroll-able.** to see all of element on the tabs by scrolling.

I'm using `native-base` for `<Tabs>` component.

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true}>
    <Tabs initialPage={0}
          tabBarUnderlineStyle={styles.tabBarUnderlineStyle}>
          <Tab
            heading="FirstTab"
            tabStyle={styles.tabStyle}
            activeTabStyle={styles.activeTabStyle}
            activeTextStyle={styles.activeTextStyle}
            textStyle={styles.textStyle}>
            <FirstScreen clothes={this.props.tops} navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
          </Tab>
          <Tab
```

I think I can't use horizontal `<ScrollView>` because `<FirstScreen>` is wrapped by `<ScrollView>`

```
let styles = RkStyleSheet.create(theme => ({
  tabStyle : {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: 60, <---- This doesn't work either. It is always (window width)/5
    height: 40
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works!!

```
      <Tabs initialPage={0}
        tabBarUnderlineStyle={styles.tabBarUnderlineStyle}
        renderTabBar={()=> <ScrollableTab style={{height:40}}/>}>
```